# Capture Bigquery data changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, scd, event-arc

I have a bigquery table that I want to capture data changes. Let's say the table has a userid and a repeated string field for tag. Every time the a tag is deleted or new tag is created, it should save a row in another table, with the DELETE/INSERT type and the tag.

I already saw the EventArc trigger + Cloud functions architecture described [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events). But this approach, doesn't contain the actual data (userid, tag), only Bigquery event metadata.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using a microservice approach -- that all delete/writes go to a microservices, which handles the data changes?

I also thought of scheduling a query every 1 minute, but this would fail if changes are made inside that one minute.

Comment: No, there is no CDC on BigQuery for now. You have to achieve this kind of check by yourselves. In addition, BigQuery is not design for read/write single data, but for analytics and parsing tons of data. In your case, maybe a Cloud SQL database could be a better choice and you could use CDC on that type of database.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere agreed, but since it's a legacy I don't have the option to change to a SQL DB. That's why I was wondering if there was something else that I described. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an option - you can use [APPENDS TVF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history#appends-tvf) for this like in below example (using public data)

```
SELECT block_slot, block_hash, block_timestamp, status,
  _CHANGE_TYPE AS change_type,
  _CHANGE_TIMESTAMP AS change_time
FROM APPENDS(
  TABLE `bigquery-public-data.crypto_solana_mainnet_us.Transactions`, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 DAY), 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
ORDER BY change_time DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

with below output

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it works only for new rows, not for updated or deleted ones.

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Current limitations are: 
1. You can only view information about appends, not updates or deletions.
2. The data is limited to the time travel window of the table.